# Is there any GraphQL Query to start a station from track?

Tags: swift, graphql, pandora

Is there any way I can start a "Station" using a "trackID" directly? Right now I have to search for Station Factory using a "search" query. Using the first result of search query, I am setting the returned result as a "Source". That's how I am able to play the track as a station. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, you can search for the track and get the station factory that way. For example, this query:

```
query {
  search(query:"Let Me by Zayn", types:[SF], pagination: {limit: 1}) {
    items {
      ... on StationFactory {
        name
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Returns this result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Let Me",
          "id": "SF:21586:35686886"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

By including `types:[SF]` in the `search` parameters, results are limited to "station factories." Station factories (see "Station and Station Factory" in the [docs](https://developer.pandora.com/docs/reference/graphql-api/overview/things-every-developer-should-know/)) can be used to start station playback (see info on `setSource` [here](https://developer.pandora.com/docs/reference/graphql-api/playback/set-source-start-playback/)).

A similar, but slightly different path, is to search for tracks (note that we are now specifying `types:[TR]` instead of `types:[SF]`):

```
query {
  search(query:"Let Me by Zayn", types:[TR], pagination: {limit: 1}) {
    items {
      ... on Track {
        name
        artist {
          name
        }
        stationFactory {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Let Me",
          "artist": {
            "name": "ZAYN"
          },
          "stationFactory": {
            "id": "SF:21586:35686886"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

There is one caveat/edge case to consider when using `types:[TR]`. Specifically, *some* tracks will not have a stationFactory ID. The vast majority of tracks will have stationFactory IDs so this shouldn't be a major limiting factor, but it's important to have a null check here.

Finally, if you know the track ID already, you can look up all the associated metadata for that track using the handy-dandy `entity` query. Here we are pulling out the station factory ID:

```
query {
  entity(id: "TR:35686886") {
    ... on Track {
      stationFactory {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "entity": {
      "stationFactory": {
        "id": "SF:21586:35686886"
      }
    }
  }
}
```